# Find Maximum element in given range in 2D array for each query

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given a 2D array, To find the element maximum for given sub rectangle corresponding to each query. 
For example 
for array of 3*4

1 2 3 7

13 6 34 7

12 5 7 8

for eg:
MAX in sub array between (0,0) and (1,1) is 13

MAX in sub array between (1,1) and (2,2) is 34

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking something like this:

```
int row = 0, col = 0;
cout << "please enter row and column"<<endl;
cin >> row >> col;

int** p = (int**) new int[row*col];
for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
{
    p[i] = new int[col];
    for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j)
    {
        cout << "Enter the number at position p[" << i << "][" << j << "]" << endl;
        int temp = 0;
        cin >> temp;
        p[i][j] = temp;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
{ 
    for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j)
        cout << p[i][j] << "\t";
    cout << endl;
}

cout << "Now find the max number provided rectangle co-ordinate[a,b] to [x,y]"<<endl;
cout << "please specify the starting and ending co-ordinates"<<endl;
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
int max = p[a][b];
for (int i = a; i <= c; ++i)
{
    for (int j = b; j <= d; ++j)
    {
        if (p[i][j] > max)
        {
            max = p[i][j];
        }
    }
}

cout << "max of the rectangle = " << max<<endl;
```